# Enable ear detection to pause music when using AirPods Pro on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, airpods, ear-phones

Is it possible to enable the "ear detection" function to play/pause the music when one of the AirPods Pro is removed? I know that this can be done with an iPhone, but is this valid also when using the AirPods Pro on a MacBook Pro? I am not currently able to do so.

Comment: That’s supposed to work with your Mac, yes (works on mine). Try turning bt on/off, forgetting AirPods, updating AirPods firmware etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Once the AirPods are connected, go to Bluetooth Preferences. There should be an options button next to the device. There will be a checkbox with the option to enable Automatic Ear detection.
[image: Screenshot of AirPods options in Bluetooth Preferences.]

Comment: I already have the "Automatic Ear Detection" option enabled, but still the music does not stop when I remove one of my AirPods.

Comment: Try Forgetting the Bluetooth device and re-pairing. This might help idk. Good luck!

Comment: Appreciate this answer for reminding how to turn this off so I can remove one AirPod while listening without pausing.